# Flask dynamic graphviz and SVG example

Tags: flask, graphviz

I'm trying to create a Graphviz image, however instead of saving the image and loading into the webpage, pass it as SVG.

Its sort of working, here is the example:

```
from flask import Flask
from graphviz import Graph


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/svgtest')
def svgtest():
  chart_data = Graph()

  chart_data.node('H', 'Hello')
  chart_data.node('W', 'World')
  chart_data.edge('H', 'W')

  chart_output = chart_data.pipe(format='svg')

 return render_template('svgtest.html', chart_output=chart_output)
```

In My HTML Page I have

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src={{ chart_output|safe }} />
```

However the output is not right

[image: output example]

Any help would really be great, I'm starting to talk to myself, and even that's not helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use svg just like this:

```
{{ chart_output|safe }}
```

and also, you can use png format:

```
@app.route('/')
def svgtest():
    chart_data = Graph()

    chart_data.node('H', 'Hello')
    chart_data.node('W', 'World')
    chart_data.edge('H', 'W')


    chart_output = chart_data.pipe(format='png')
    chart_output = base64.b64encode(chart_output).decode('utf-8')

    return render_template('svgtest.html', chart_output=chart_output)
```

and the html like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{chart_output|safe}}" />
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I have modified a bit.

```
from flask import Flask
from graphviz import Graph


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/svgtest')
def svgtest():
  chart_data = Graph()

  chart_data.node('H', 'Hello')
  chart_data.node('W', 'World')
  chart_data.edge('H', 'W')

  chart_output = chart_data.pipe(format='svg').encode("utf-8")

 return render_template('svgtest.html', chart_output=chart_output)
```

and the modified html will be:

```
{{chart_output|safe}}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `src` attribute of the [`embed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) tag should contain an url to the content to embed, not the content itself:

> The HTML `<embed>` element embeds external content at the specified
>   point in the document. This content is provided by an external
>   application ...
>
> `src` The URL of the resource being embedded.

If you want to use `embed`, you should serve the svg (without html template) under its own url and use that url in the `src` attribute of the `embed` tag.

Or you may insert the svg directly in your html template, without the `embed` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you show me, with an example or my example, I think I follow you but I'm still not 100% sure